# GKE Autopilot failing to create new deployment after 10-12 deployments saying "Insufficient CPU"

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, autopilot

I am having some issue with GKE(autopilot).

I am deploying statefulsets and for each statefulset I deploy a service with public IP.
But after deploying like 10-12 statefulsets, if I try deploying any new it remains  red(Unschedulable) with message "Insufficient cpu".

When I go to cluster section is show a different message saying:

```
Can’t scale up because instances in managed instance groups hosting node pools ran out of IPs
```

Image of error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/acFxZ.png

I am new to GKE and tried doing what suggested in links of those image but it seems most of steps give error saying its not supported in autopilot mode.

Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: When you created your Autopilot cluster, did you assign an IP range or did you let Autopilot handle that for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on **GKE autopilot** ideally it will create the new nodes in cluster if out of CPU or no space left to schedule the PODs.

However if it's issue of IP you can read more : https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/alias-ips#not_enough_space

> Cluster autoscaler might not have enough unallocated IP address space
> to use to add new nodes or Pods, resulting in scale-up failures, which
> are indicated by [eventResult events](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-autoscaler-visibility#eventresult-event) with the reason
> `scale.up.error.ip.space.exhausted`. You can add more IP addresses for
> nodes by [expanding the primary subnet](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc#expand-subnet), or add new IP addresses for
> Pods using [discontiguous multi-Pod CIDR](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/multi-pod-cidr). For more information, see [Not
> enough free IP space for Pods](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/alias-ips#not_enough_space).

but you are on autopilot so wont be able to access underlaying subnet and node pools of cluster maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the only option at this point is to create a new cluster and make sure that the CIDR ranges you assign to the cluster have enough available IPs for the number of nodes you believe you'll need.  The default setting for Autopilot should be enough.